# Placing a full width footer under floating divs?

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a website where I want a full width footer th. But it currently looks like this: [image]

Though I want it to look like this:

[image]

Im not sure if it is the css that I am using which is:

You can see the full css and html here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Mzmtv/

For a full-website version: lrch.harisonbh.com

```
/*I'm not sure if this is possible or not, with using the floating divs*/
```

Basically i need the footer div that exists to be similar to the one in the second picture. Thanks

Comment: lrch.harisonbh.com isnt working

Comment: Set its width to 100% and place it outside the main container, that limits the page size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Below demo and code is only for footer as per your request.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mzmtv/3/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mzmtv/3/embedded/result

Insted of below html Structure

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="footer">
        &copy;<!--?php echo date("Y") ?--> Little Rock Central High     <a href="#top"><p>Back To Top</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**you should use this one :**

```
<div id="footer_container">
    <div class="footer">
        &copy;<!--?php echo date("Y") ?--> Little Rock Central High     <a href="#top"><p>Back To Top</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer_container {
    clear: both; 
    margin-top: 194px; 
    z-index: 1; 
    width: 100%; 
    background: #333333;
}

.footer {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**Screen Shot:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="footer">
        &copy;Little Rock Central High<a href="#top"><p>Back To Top</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="footer">
    &copy;Little Rock Central High<a href="#top"><p>Back To Top</p></a>
</div>
```

Where

```
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The address you gave does not work.  I will give you an answer based on the most likely problem:

You said you have a footer "th" which confused me as you said you were using DIVs.  I will assume you are using divs and answer accordingly.

1. Place the div outside the main wrapper div (below all content and in the  tags most likely
2. Place an element in the code that has the style settings of `clear:both`.  For example, you can use:

   `<br style="clear:both;" />`
3. Put 100% width on the footer div `width:100%;`

Comment: Can you make a jSfiddle, im not sure if i follow what you mean, Thanks. Also i update the address.

Answer (score -2):

Use moar nested divs

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="head-inner" style="width: 920px;">
            <a href="#">Little Rock High School</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="body-inner" style="width: 100%; background-color: #ccc">
        <div class="container" style="width: 920px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer" style="width 100%; background-color: #222;">
          <p>Footer stuff</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Set the container class to `position: relative;` and then float your elements with `position: absolute; float: left;` - this is seemingly very common (hell, you could probably use bootstrap for a solid grid for those if you wanted)

Comment: @Zipp could you make a js fiddle? Im note sure what you mean, thansk